Calculating the expected cost of defective products
Problem:
A particular sale involves four items randomly selected from a large lot
that is known to contain $10\%$ defectives. Let $Y$ denote the number  of
defectives among the four sold. The purchaser of the items will return the
defectives for repair and  the repair cost is given by $C = 3Y^2 + Y + 2$. Find
the  expected repair cost.
Hint: The result of Theorem 3.4 implies that for any random
variable, $Y$, $E(Y) = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 $.
\newline
Answer:
\newline
Let $e_c$ be the expected value we seek. Let $p_0$ be the probability that there are no
defective elements. Let $p_1$ be the probability of exactly one item being defective. Let $p_2$ be the probability of exactly two items being defective.
Let $p_3$ and $p_4$ be defined similarly. The number of defective items is a binomial distribution with $p = 0.1$ and $q = 0.9$. The general forumla for the binomial
distribution is:
$$ p(y) = { n \choose y } p^y q^{n-y} $$ We can find $e_c$ using the following:
$$e_c = p_0C(0) + p_1C(1) + p_2C(2) + p_3 C(3) + p_4 C(4) $$
Now we compute $p_0$ and $p_1$.
\begin{align*}
p_0 &= .9^4 \\
p_1 &= { 4 \choose 1 } (0.1)(0.9^3) \\
p_1 &= 4 (0.1)(0.9^3) = 0.4(0.9^3) \\
\end{align*}
Now we compute $p_2$.
\begin{align*}
p_2 &= { 4 \choose 2 } (0.1^2)(0.9^2) \\ 
{ 4 \choose 2 } &= \dfrac{4(3)}{2} = 6 \\
p_2 &= 6(0.1^2)(0.9^2) \\ 
\end{align*}
Now we compute $p_3$.
\begin{align*}
p_3 &= { 4 \choose 3 } (0.1^3)(0.9) \\
{ 4 \choose 3 } &= \dfrac{ 4}{1} = 4 \\
p_3 &= 4(0.1^3)(0.9) = 3.6(0.1^3) \\
\end{align*}
Now we compute $p_4$.
\begin{align*}
p_4 &= 0.1^4 \\ 
\end{align*}
Now we compute, $C(0)$, $C(1)$, $C(2)$, $ C(3)$ and $C(4) $.
\begin{align*}
C(0) &=  301^2) + 0 + 2 \\
C(0) &= 2 \\
C(1) &=  3(1^2) + 1 + 2 = 3 + 1 + 2 \\
C(1) &= 6 \\
C(2) &=  3(2^2) + 2 + 2  = 12 + 2 + 2 \\
C(2) &= 16  \\
C(3) &= 3(3^2) + 3 + 2 = 27 + 3 + 2 \\
C(3) &= 32  \\
C(4) &= 3(4^2) + 4 + 2 = 3(16) + 4 + 2 \\
C(4) &= 54 
\end{align*}
Now we can find $e_c$.
\begin{align*}
e_c &=
 .9^4(2) + 0.4(0.9^3)( 6 ) +  6(0.1^2)(0.9^2)(16) + 3.6(0.1^3)(32) + 0.1^4 (54) \\
%
e_c &=  1.3122 + 1.7496 +   0.7776000 + 0.1152000 +0.0054000 \\
e_c &= 3.96
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ 3.96 $$
Hence, I match the book. However, I did not use the hint. Should I have? Since I did
not I get the feeling I may have done something wrong.

The hint should actually say
$$\operatorname{E}[Y^{\color{red}{2}}] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2.$$
To use the hint, you would apply the linearity of expectation:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[C]
&= \operatorname{E}[3Y^2 + Y + 2] \\
&= 3\operatorname{E}[Y^2] + \operatorname{E}[Y] + 2 \\
&= 3(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + \mu + 2.
\end{align}$$
Then note that for $$Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 4, p = 0.10),$$
we have $$\mu = \operatorname{E}[Y] = np = 0.4, \quad \sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[Y] = np(1-p) = 0.36.$$  Hence
$$\operatorname{E}[C] = 3(0.36 + (0.4)^2) + 0.4 + 2 = 3.96.$$
Your approach also works, but involves more computation.

The hint  in the book is correct. I dropped the 2 when I typed in the formula.
